# fslex - matching issues line terminator

Tags: f#, lexer, fslex

please consider this piece of a lexer I am constructing:

```
let newline = "\n\r" | '\n' | '\r'
let dot = "\."
let lineTerminator  = "\."newline

rule tokenize = parse
  ...
  | lineTerminator  { lexbuf.EndPos <- lexbuf.EndPos.NextLine; tokenize lexbuf; }
  | newline         { lexbuf.EndPos <- lexbuf.EndPos.NextLine; tokenize lexbuf }
  | eof             { EOF }
  | _ { failwithf "unrecognized input: '%s'" <| lexeme lexbuf }
```

On a line terminating with a dot, the current buffer will be at the character where the dot is and say that it **cannot recognize the input**.

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.